# Column `project` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Tags: r

I have data frame called df ,I need to filter data from data frame using filter().pls check

my data frame

```
Queue   project._id   project.ProjectName    project.Status  project.CreatedBy  project.Createdtime     X.gender

first     111              Travel                1               manchi         2017-04-24 18:50:27       male

last      111              2334                  1               mono             2017-04-24 18:50:27      Female

first     111              556                  1               gunal            2017-04-24 18:50:27       male

first     7888            classical             1               manchi            2017-04-24 18:50:27      Female
```

I'm try to use dplyr to filter data By below code.

```
Finalfilter<-df%>% 
   filter(project.ProjectName == "Travel",Queue=="first")%>%
    select(X.gender.)
```

my expected result is

```
Queue   project._id   project.ProjectName    project.Status  project.CreatedBy  project.Createdtime     X.gender

first     111              Travel                1               manchi         2017-04-24 18:50:27       male

first     111              556                  1               gunal            2017-04-24 18:50:27       male
```

But i'm getting below ERROR ,help me to resolve this.

> Error: Column `project` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

dput.

```
structure(list(Queue = c("first", "last", "first", "first"), 
    project = structure(list(`_id` = c("111", "2334", "556", 
    "7888"), ProjectName = c("Travel", "HBussiness", "Travel", 
    "classical"), Status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), CreatedBy = c("manchi", 
    "mono", "gunal", "manchi"), Createdtime = structure(c(1493040027.826, 
    1493040027.826, 1493040027.826, 1493040027.826), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("_id", "ProjectName", "Status", "CreatedBy", 
    "Createdtime"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    X.gender. = c("male", "Female", "male", "Female")), .Names = c("Queue", 
"project", "X.gender."), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `project.ProjectName` is a data frame, not a vector, hence the error. A workaround can be,

```
df$project <- df$project$ProjectName

df%>% 
     filter(project == "Travel" & Queue=="first")%>%
     select(X.gender.)

#  X.gender.
#1      male
#2      male
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work with dplyr another option is:

```
df[df$project.ProjectName == "Travel" & Queue=="first", ]
```